# How to do two-level many-to-many relationships?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working in Flask with Flask-SQLAlchemy, and trying to setup a many-to-many-to-many relationship: clients can have multiple orders and orders can also have multiple clients (many to many); each order in turn contains a list of unique items (one to many).

I followed the SQLAlchemy documents to setup an association table for the many-to-many relationship, and used the normal relationship/foreign key for the one-to-many relationship; all references are set to `lazy='dynamic'`.

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
)
```

what is an efficient way to retrieve all `items` associated with a client? I'm assuming `[item for item in order.items.all() for order in client.orders]` will work (less the problem above), but is there more efficient way to do it? What if the results needs to be ordered?

---

**Update**

I now know two ways to retrieve the items for the orders of a client by the following two methods (the first one from Audrius' answer):

```
db.session.query(Item).\
    join(Order).join(Order.clients).\
    filter(Client.id == 42).\
    order_by(Item.timestamp)
```

and

```
Item.query.filter(Item.order_id._in(client.order_ids)).order_by(Item.timestamp)‌​
```

I believe they both provide the same result, but which one should be preferred for efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing query directly in SQL, you would be using joins to retrieve the data you want efficiently (as Rachcha demonstrated in his answer). The same applies to SQLAlchemy. Refer to the SA docs on [`join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) for more examples.

If your model is defined like the following (using Flask-SQLAlchemy, since you tagged your question with its tag):

```py
clients_orders = db.Table('clients_orders',
    db.Column('client_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('client.id'),
              primary_key=True),
    db.Column('order_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order.id'),
              primary_key=True)
)

class Client(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    orders = db.relationship('Order', secondary=clients_orders,
                             backref='clients')
    # Define other columns...

class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Define other columns...

class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order.id'), nullable=False)
    order = db.relationship('Order', backref='items')
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    # Define other columns...
```

Then your query could look like this:

```py
db.session.query(Item).\
    join(Order).join(Order.clients).\
    filter(Client.id == 42).\
    order_by(Item.timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy, and my schema setup is almost identical to your answer. I am wondering if your query should be preferred to something like `Item.query.filter(Item.order_id._in(client.order_ids)).order_by(Item.timestamp)`, where order_ids is implemented with an association proxy. I am guessing that yours will be more efficient for its simpler filter logic. Is this right?

Comment: Your query requires you to already have `client` and all `order` objects related to it. So that's at least one additional query which is not needed, unless your code logic requires it. You would also have a hard time adding more complex filter conditions to it. Regarding speed, the best way to tell which is quicker is to try SQL code rendered by both SA queries with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and real data.